# Terminal zoom in / zoom out shortcut doesn't work in Ubuntu22.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, 22.04, shortcuts

I am new to Ubuntu, and I chose the latest version 22.04 LTS.
But I have an issue that’s really confusing me.

- **The shortcut for "zoom in" and "zoom out" in the terminal doesn't work** 
  Every time I open a new terminal, the size of the terminal is too small to use, but I can't use the default shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom in or zoom out.

I already solved the problem in another way: *menu -> "unnamed(default)" under Profiles -> click the Custom font and set the Terminal font to 14(choose the size you want)*.

But I still want to figure out why the shortcut doesn't work and how to solve it.

- **I can't set the shortcut by myself while typing in <kbd>ctrl</kbd>**

Trying to fix this problem, I chose to set the shortcut by typing `New accelerator` into the setting.

However, *the button <kbd>ctrl</kbd> can't be accepted and the new became the only `+`, I have to disable shortcuts in case of need for inputting `+`, which perplexed me for a long time.*

Sorry for not showing my picture because of my low reputation(first time asking).

Thanks for reading and providing solutions!

[shortcut setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Movcj.png)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're actually typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>.

Try using the <kbd>shift</kbd> key to get the "+" character: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>.

(Yes, it's annoying that it literally needs the "+" rather than simply that key.)

Comment: Thanks! I changed my shortcut to `ctrl` `shift` `+` which solved my problem. And thanks for editing my issue!